# PHP json_encode turning string to null

Tags: php, json, encryption

I am trying to figure out an issue with a PHP script I'm writing. Essentially, this script is using the [phpseclib library](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to encrypt a password using a public RSA key passed to it by a ASP.NET application. The password seems to be getting encrypted fine, but when I attempt to put the encrypted string into an json string, it gets turned into NULL.

Code:

```php
// Create our RSA encryption object
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

// Get modulus and exponent for our public key
// ($keyInner was gathered from the keygen server)
$modulus = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($keyInner->{'Modulus'}), 256);
$exponent = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($keyInner->{'Exponent'}), 256);

// Generate our public key and padding scheme
$rsa->loadKey(array('n' => $modulus, 'e' => $exponent));
$rsa->setPublicKey();
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);

// Gather user data
// In reality this is gathered from a form but for 
// example's sake I'll be using static values
$username = 'foo';
$password = 'boo';

// Encrypt password
$password = $rsa->encrypt($password);
// $password == <some encrypted string>
// gettype($password) == string
// mb_detect_encoding == UTF_8

// Create json
$arr = json_encode(array(
    'payload' => array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
    )
));

// $arr = {"payload":{"username":"Bob","password":null}}
```

Comment: @RyanVincent does the fact that 1) it's running over https and 2) it's an internal application change that?

Answer (score 3):

`json_encode` doesn't work well with binary data, you'd be better off `base64_encode`ing it:

```
// Create json
$arr = json_encode(array(
    'payload' => array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => base64_encode($password),
    )
));
```

And then decode it on the recieving end.

Comment: JSON is using UTF-8 by definition. It cannot be used to transport binary data.

Comment: Although this would work, unfortunately the decryption process on the other end (i.e., the ASP.NET project) is expecting UTF-8. I unfortunately can't change anything on that end (it's not my project). I was just told to implement it haha.

Comment: You'll have to explain that you cannot transmit plain binary data using JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the data is not UTF-8 valid so it fails to encode.

You can use [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to detect what the actual problem is if $arr returns null.

Comment: Actually just got to that point. It is the JSON_ERROR_UTF8 error being given. Now trying to track down what's causing it.